# Loading remote libraries in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, dllimport, loadlibrary

I know a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595411/how-to-load-dll-library-remotely) has already been asked here but nobody seems to have answered it.The project I'm working on requires these features.

1. A dll has to be loaded from the server to the program running at client side.
2. The native methods in the dll has to access a set of files present in the 
   server.
3. The invocation of native methods happen at the client side.

Thank you!

Comment: and which step are you stuck with and why

Comment: I see no question here. I see a list of requirements, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+--------------+                       +--------+
| Client (JVM) | - 1. download DLL --> | Server |
+--------------+                       +--------+
  | |      ^                               |         
  | |      |                               |
  | |      |                               |
  | |      +------- 2. DLL-----------------+
  | |
  | |
  | +-- 3. save DLL into temporary location --+
  |                                           |
  |                                           |
  |                                          \ /
  |                                    /tmp/some_file
  |                                    
  |
  +--- 4. load file using System.load

To access files on server do one of these (few loose ideas):

- map disk or mount SMB resources
- implement RMI inside native code loaded into JVM via JNI
- implement remote access to files
```